# problem while connecting google search console with analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I am using search console and analytics with the same e-mail address. I wanted to link search console with analytics so, I went to search console > settings > Associations. I found the associate button disabled. When I hovered over it it tells that we couldn't  find a google analytics property for "my mail". But I have used the same mail for analytics and search console. Please help me. Waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your Google Analytics account is a new GA4 one and not the previous Universal (GA3) one. If the sidebar contains a "Monetisation" option it is GA4.

Connecting to GA4 is not possible yet.

Comment: Yeah it's GA4. Can we do the integration in search console?

Comment: Not yet. You could add both as data sources in a Data Studio report and blend them together to get reports that combine them both.